# Display Model name instead of 'Users' on the admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I've created a custom user model using abstractuser titled employee.

```
class Employee(AbstractUser):

username = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
user_type = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', null = True)
status = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='Not Verified',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

That is my models.py pertaining to Employee

On the Admin page I see this - [Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB0q2.png)

Learningsys is my app name.

How do I make it so that I see ''Employee or preferably 'Employees' under my app name instead of 'Users' and why does it show Users in the first place? I suspect it is because I am technically creating a 'Custom User' but would like clarification regardless.

Thanks,

Rohan.

Comment: The code you have shown would *not* display Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`verbose_name_plural`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural) meta option to change model's plural name on admin page:

```
class Employee(AbstractUser):
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Employees'
```

The default value of `verbose_name_plural` for `AbstractUser` is `users` so you inherited it with other AbstractUser's properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I had tried verbose_name_plural outside Meta (didn't create a Meta class) but in hindsight that was silly.